# Find and replace specific number that matches pattern without changing the whole string

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

i'm using Sublime text 3 search function with regular expressions enabled.
I have a big text file, that has text strings surrounded by square brackets in it.
For example:

```
blah blah bla bhal [e9] blah blah bla bhal blah blah 9 5 4
bla bhal blah blah bla bhal[`5b7k7s]
blah blah bla bhal blah blah bla bhal 
[^5bd9`ke93n]
```

I want to replace specific numbers in square brackets with other symbols. For example i want to change 9 to A, so i need the example above to be like this:

```
blah blah bla bhal [eA] blah blah bla bhal blah blah 9 5 4
bla bhal blah blah bla bhal[`5b7k7s]
blah blah bla bhal blah blah bla bhal 
[^5bdA`keA3n]
```

(Mention that 9 not in sqare brackets has not been changed)

I was trying to capture the number with regular expression like this

> ```
>       \[?9?\]
> ```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @CinCout i'm not good at regex, i was trying something like this \[?9?\] but it will point only [9] type strings

Comment: @CinCout did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working with notepad++, I guess it also works with Sublimetext.

- Find : `\[[^\]]*?\K9`
- Replace : `A`

You have to click on replace all as many times as needed to replace all `9` (if there are many) in a single bracket. Like `[^5bd9ke93n]` you have to click twice.

**Explanation:**

```
\[      : open bracket
[^\]]*? : negative character class (ie. not a close bracket), 0 or more times, not greedy
\K      : forget all we have seen until this position
9       : literally 9
```